# XBee Shield Association LED

Tags: arduino, xbee

I bought [XBee shield from dfrobot](http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/Xbee_Shield_For_Arduino_%28no_Xbee%29_%28SKU:DFR0015%29) to do communication with XBee module and Arduino. This is how the shield looks like:

[image: XBee Shield]

The question is, what is the meaning of the state of Association LED blinking?

Answer (score 2):

Check the [XBEE datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Zigbee/XBee-Datasheet.pdf) for the meaning of 'Association'.

[image: XBee Terms and Definitions]

As I read it, it indicates if a *Coordinator* had teamed up with an *End Device or Router* or not, and whether they can communicate or not.

At page 17 there is a chapter on Association. Search for `Associate LED` in that document.

> 3) **Start Coordinator**
>
> The Coordinator starts on the specified channel (CH parameter) and PAN
>   ID (ID parameter). Note, these may be selected in steps 1 and/or 2
>   above. The Coordinator will only allow End Devices to associate to it
>   if the A2 parameter “AllowAssociation” flag is set. Once the
>   Coordinator has successfully started, the **Associate LED will blink 1
>   time per second**. (The LED is solid if the Coordinator has not
>   started.)

...

> 1) **Check A1 parameter - AutoAssociate Bit**
>
> Set (bit 2 = 1)
>   - End Device will attempt to associate to a Coordinator. (refer to steps 2-3). Not Set (bit 2 = 0)
>   - End Device will not attempt to associate to a Coordinator. The End Device will operate as specified by its ID, CH and MY parameters.
>   Association is considered complete and the **Associate LED will blink
>   quickly (5 times per second)**. When the AutoAssociate bit is not set,
>   the remaining step s (2-3) do not apply.

...

> 3) **Associate to Valid Coordinator**
>
> Once a valid Coordinator is found (step 2), the End Device sends an
>   AssociationRequest message to the Coordinator. It then waits for an
>   AssociationConfirmation to be sent from the Coordinator. Once the
>   Confirmation is received, the End Device is Associated and the
>   **Associate LED will blink rapidly (2 times per second).** The LED is solid if the End Device has not associated.

Comment: does that state (number 2, associate led blink 5 seconds) has any connection to the module when entering sleep mode? because, as I watched, when XBee entering sleep mode, the associate LED blinked quickly (about 5 times) per second. By the way, thank you for the clear answer :).

Comment: In the circuit diagram you can see the LED is connected to the module. http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/images/0/02/XBeeShield_SCH.png